# Outlook is breaking my email

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

Having some issues with an email I am designing. I am trying to have the three tables alongside each other, with the next three below (but done so when I view it on mobile it will be one after the other.) This works well in email clients like yahoo and hotmail but it starts breaking in outlook, where two will be side by side with the next table being below (creating a huge space on the right side of the email.)  I am quite new to email design, so any help would be brilliant.

```
<table width="593" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="593"><table style="float: left;" align="center"
                    border="0" width="196" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
                            <td width="5" colspan="3" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="5" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="84" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table style="float: left;" align="center" border="0" width="196"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
                            <td width="5" colspan="3" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="5" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="84" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table style="float: left;" align="center" border="0" width="196"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
                            <td width="5" colspan="3" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="5" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="84" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <table style="float: left;" align="center" border="0" width="196"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
                            <td width="5" colspan="3" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="5" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="84" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table style="float: left;" align="center" border="0" width="196"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
                            <td width="5" colspan="3" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="5" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="84" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table style="float: left;" align="center" border="0" width="196"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="5" colspan="3"></td>
                            <td width="5" colspan="3" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="5" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="84" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is probably the 'Outlook page-break bug'. See my answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5662054/582278, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5662156/582278

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML email - Outlook 2007+10, unrelated tables aligning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630718/html-email-outlook-200710-unrelated-tables-aligning)

Comment: I looked at those posts and tried adding: <br style="line-height:0 ; height:0 ; font-size:0"> but it made no difference....

Comment: It all depends where your images fall - if it's around the position where a new sheet of A4 would start, you hit this bug. Outlook will attempt to move the content 'onto the next page'. To see the problem more clearly, open the HTML in Word (which is the rendering engine used by Outlook). If you can force a break in the image somewhere, that can help.

Answer (score 0):

you can get around this outlook bug by putting your content in completely separate tables like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:36px;">SOME HEADER CONTENT TO GO IN HERE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="593"><table style="float: left;" align="center" border="0" width="196"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td width="84" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
              <table style="float: left;" align="center" border="0" width="196"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td width="84" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table style="float: left;" align="center" border="0" width="196"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td width="84" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="593"><table style="float: left;" align="center" border="0" width="196"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td width="84" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table style="float: left;" align="center" border="0" width="196"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td width="84" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table style="float: left;" align="center" border="0" width="196"
                    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><img
                                    src="entertainment.gif" alt="" width="38" height="38"
                                    align="left" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Magazine
                                        Subsription</strong><br> &nbsp; Some awesome stuff</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><a target="_blank"
                                href="LINK"><img style="display: block;" src="IMAGE"
                                    alt="Parrot Rolling Spider" border="0" height="190" width="190"></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td width="84" height="26" bgcolor="#ffffff"><span
                                style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">12,000
                                    Points</span></td>
                            <td width="101" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table align=""
                                    width="101" height="26" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr valign="middle" align="center" width="300" height="10"
                                        bgcolor="#8ec043" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                        <td valign="middle"
                                            style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                                            width="83" height="24"><div align="center">
                                                <a href="LINK"
                                                    style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; width: 100%; display: inline-block"><span
                                                    style="color: #FFFFFF">Spend Points</span></a>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td width="16" valign="middle"><a href="LINK"><img
                                                src="http://www.maximiles.co.uk/images/dynamics/uk/email_images/ftpIMAGES2014/maximile-email-elements2014/arrow.gif"
                                                alt="" width="12" height="16" align="left" /></a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:36px;">FOOTER<br />
      Ts&amp;Cs to go here as well</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, avoid rowspan and colspan - use nested tables instead. I have amended this in the code above